# Replacing variable A that contains document.location.path if variable B is not undefined

Tags: javascript, function, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Google Tag Manager in default configuration sends a pageview based on a variable **{{Page URL}}**. This variable contains document.location.pathname.

The website I'm working on has a global js variable **trackerParam** that modifies the page URL sent to different analytics engines. In most of the cases, it's undefined.

What I need to do is to write a custom javascript variable for Google Tag Manager, that, by default, would grab document.location.pathname, except for cases where trackerParam is not undefined. Then, it should replace the variable with trackerParam value.

I can't get it to work. The console.log part is there just for debugging.

```
function impPageUrl()
{
    var = PageUrl;
    if (trackerParam != undefined)   
    {  
        return trackerParam;
        console.log(trackerParam);
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return document.location.pathname;
        console.log(document.location.pathname);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function impPageUrl(w,d)
{
    var dlp = d.location.pathname;

    if (typeof(w.PageUrl) != "undefined" && w.PageUrl != undefined)   
    {  
        console.log(w.PageUrl);
        return w.PageUrl;        
    }  

    else  
    {  
        console.log(dlp);
        return dlp;        
    }
})(window,document)
```

Comment: This actually made it work, but it turns out some of the pages don't have the global variable trackerParam. What code modification would you have to do in order to treat no trackerParam the same way as trackerParam=undefined?

Comment: I rewrite it little bit so this should fits your needs